# How to remove columns from ExtJs grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I need to remove some columns on condition of user login. I have created a grid containing some columns. I need to remove username and password column when user login and want to show it on admin user login. so user can't able to see usernames and passwords in these column. only admin can see these columns.
I used hidden Config like`hidden : true` on user login but user can unhide it using grid's internal tool. So, I want to completely remove these columns from that grid when user get login.
You can see below is my sample ExtJs code. I didn't found any config in sencha/Extjs doc to completely remove these column using condition. Please give me solution on this. how can I do in that way.

```
Ext.define('fleet.view.Vehiclelist', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    initComponent: function () {

        Ext.apply(this, {
            layout: 'fit',
            columns: [{
                header: 'Vehicle Id',
                dataIndex: 'vehicleId',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                header: 'Vehicle No',
                dataIndex: 'vehicleNo',
                flex: 1
            },{
                header: 'Username',
                dataIndex: 'username',
                flex: 1,
                hidden: this.isAdmin == true ? false : true
            }, {
                header: 'Password',
                dataIndex: 'password',
                flex: 1,
                hidden: this.isAdmin == true ? false : true
            }]
        });
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Below image showing when I am login with user, this get hide columns but even user can able to show it by using grid internal tools of show/hide columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `hiding` you can add dynamic columns inside of `initComponent` method. If user type is `admin` then add into the columns otherwise nothing to do.

In this **[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2jm7)**, I have created a demo using simple login `window` and `grid`.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('Vehiclelist', {
            extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
            xtype:'vehiclelist',
            initComponent: function () {
                let columns = [{
                    header: 'Vehicle Id',
                    dataIndex: 'vehicleId',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    header: 'Vehicle No',
                    dataIndex: 'vehicleNo',
                    flex: 1
                }];
                if (this.isAdmin) {
                    columns.push({
                        header: 'Username',
                        dataIndex: 'username',
                        flex: 1
                    }, {
                        header: 'Password',
                        dataIndex: 'password',
                        flex: 1
                    });
                }
                Ext.apply(this, {
                    layout: 'fit',
                    columns: columns
                });
                this.callParent();
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'Login',
            width: 350,
            layout: 'vbox',
            closable: false,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                labelAlign: 'top',
                width: '100%'
            },
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'Username'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                inputType: 'password'
            }],
            bbar: ['->', {
                text: 'Login',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    Ext.destroy(btn.up('window'));
                    Ext.create({
                        xtype:'vehiclelist',
                        title:'With username and password',
                        renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
                        isAdmin:true
                    });

                    Ext.create({
                        xtype:'vehiclelist',
                        margin:'20 0',
                        title:'Without username and password',
                        renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
                        isAdmin:false
                    });
                }
            }]
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanx... 
I used splice() Insted of push() so i get my columns where I want. 
 this.columnsArr.splice(3, 0, {
                header: 'Password',
                dataIndex: 'password',
                flex: 1,
            });
            this.columnsArr.splice(3, 0, {
                header: 'Username',
                dataIndex: 'username',
                flex: 1,
            });

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20276935 - the answer was already given before the link; please be more careful when reviewing answers in the queue.

Comment: @TylerH I did't understand what you want to say.

Comment: @NarendraJadhav You voted to delete the answer but it should not have been deleted.

Comment: @TylerH so only I am given the vote for delete other user also given the vote to delete. This is not deleted only with the help of my vote. there are also 3 more users given the vote for deletion.

Comment: @NarendraJadhav And I've let them all know of the mistake, too.